# Data not loading on Line Chart - using jQuery AJAX. and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using simple line chart from google charts and the data is not loading I only need two values to appear the hours worked and the days of that particular month.
I am able to store data in an array but I wish to pull from the database.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

    //Load the Visualization API library and the linechart library.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

    //Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawLoseATonLineChart);

    //Callback that creates and populates a data table, instantiates the line chart,
    //passes in the data, and draws it.
    function drawLoseATonLineChart() {

        var url = "@Url.Action("GetChartStatistics")";

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([jsonData[i].Date, jsonData[i].Hours]);
        }

        var options = {
            title: 'Employees hours worked',
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                alignment: 'center'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Weight'
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Week',
                slantedText: true,
                slantedTextAngle: 45

            },
            colors: ['E81A00']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lose-a-ton-line-chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

My controller
`GetStatisics()` method

```
           var line = (from a in db.employees
            join p in db.time
                on a.id = p.id
            where a.Username == currentuser
            select new line
            {
                Date = a.Datecaptured,
                 Hours = a.Hours
            });

return Json(line, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Please Help

Comment: I assume you mean `for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {` (not `data.length`)

Comment: yes sir i think  so but in my controller  m still getting an error

Comment: You calling `GetChartStatistics` but shown us `GetStatisics`. And how can we possible know what error you have when you post incomplete code and do not tell us what error your getting.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake there... var line part the word line is getting underlined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change  jsonData.length instead of data.length**

```
function drawLoseATonLineChart() {

var url = "@Url.Action("GetChartStatistics")";

var jsonData = $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false
}).responseText;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');
//just put "jsonData"  instead of  "data"
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
         data.addRow([jsonData[i].Date, jsonData[i].Hours]);
     }
var options = {
    title: 'Employees hours worked',
    legend: {
        position: 'right',
        alignment: 'center'
    },
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Weight'
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Week',
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 45

    },
    colors: ['E81A00']
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lose-a-ton-line-chart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

}